# margin: 0 auto not working even with display: block

Tags: html, css

I've looked for the answer here and tried everything, but I can't find a solution that works for my case. So I've decided to ask:

I want to center horizontally the div "listapost" (contained in the div "heart", width 100%). "Listapost" contains a certain number of "post" divs, 2 or 3 per rows according to the total width of the screen. This is the css:

```
#heart{width:100%}

#post{
width:50px;
float:left;
text-align:left;
padding:5px;
margin:1px;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
color:#605f5f;
background-color:#f7f6f6;
}

#listapost{margin:0 auto;}
```

the HTML is something like this:

```
<div id="heart">
     <div id="listapost">
       <div id="post">stuff</div>
       <div id="post">stuff</div>
       <div id="post">stuff</div>
       ....
     </div>
</div>
```

Even using "display: inline-block" and removing the float property of "post" the "listapost" div is not centered. Why?

Comment: You have to specify the `width` of `#listapost` explicitly to make auto margins to work. For instance: `#listapost{ width: 70%; margin:0 auto; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Initial Problem

You need to specify a `width` on your `#listapost` element, otherwise the width of that and your `#heart` elements are identical, and it's already in the middle.

```css
#heart{width:100%}

#post{
width:50px;
float:left;
text-align:left;
padding:5px;
margin:1px;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
color:#605f5f;
background-color:#f7f6f6;
}

#listapost{margin:0 auto; width: 220px;}
```

```html
<div id="heart">
     <div id="listapost">
       <div id="post">stuff</div>
       <div id="post">stuff</div>
       <div id="post">stuff</div>
       ....
     </div>
</div>
```

### A better solution

A better solution is to remove the `float` values on your `#post` items and instead give them an `inline-block` display, then you can simply set your `#postalist` element to have central `text-align`.

```css
#heart{width:100%}

#post{
width:50px;
display: inline-block;
text-align:left;
padding:5px;
margin:1px;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
color:#605f5f;
background-color:#f7f6f6;
}

#listapost{text-align: center;}
```

```html
<div id="heart">
     <div id="listapost">
       <div id="post">stuff</div>
       <div id="post">stuff</div>
       <div id="post">stuff</div>
       ....
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In addition, you might want to consider [removing the gap between inline-block elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements).

Comment: Thanks a lot, the "better solution" have worked fine!

Comment: @phatejoker happy to help. :-) Could you please mark this as the accepted answer when you get the chance? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

change css rule #listapost to

```
#listapost{
 display:table;
 margin:0px auto;}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pq3xrch9/)

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: table;` to `#listapost` like this:

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w0zd7pzb/)

```css
#heart {
    width:100%
}
#post {
    width:50px;
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
    padding:5px;
    margin:1px;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#605f5f;
    background-color:#f7f6f6;
}
#listapost {
    display: table;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="heart">
    <div id="listapost">
        <div id="post">stuff</div>
        <div id="post">stuff</div>
        <div id="post">stuff</div>
        ....
  </div>
</div>
```